# How to record using AVAudioRecorder without the .caf container?

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder, aac, m4a, caf

I am using a AVAudioRecorder instance to record with the setting for `AVFormatIDKey`  set to `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC`.  It records the audio in AAC format but a `.caf` audio container packages the audio file. (I can see the caff header in the recorder file).
How do I record so that the caff container is not there but in pure m4a format so that I can use the files across platforms.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer.
There is a weird way the AVAudioRecorder works.

**The format in which the AVAudioRecorder will save your file depends on the URL/string you specify for the file you save. It depends on the extension of the file name you are saving.**

If you don't specify any extension or one that the recorder can't understand then it will add the Core Audio container.
So, basically see to that the extension and the `AVFormatIDKey` match.
Like for `aac` use format use `.aac` extension with `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` as the `AVFormatIDKey`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796064/avaudiorecorder-initwithurl-file-type-documentation